# removing an element from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am playing with the following code from this webpage

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

Everything works fine but I am having trouble removing the scroller after use, for example if I want to change the content of the page.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an ID to the scroller element and use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changecontent() {
    document.getElementById('scroller').style.display = 'none';
    // or
    document.getElementById('scroller').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // or completely remove the HTML element
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('scroller'));
}
</script>

<div id="scroller"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
<p><a href="javascript:changecontent()">Change content</a></p>
```

Comment: You have to use them in a function.

Comment: I did use them in a function.

Comment: however if I include the display:none line in the div tag itself it does disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you encase your scrolling image box in a div tag you could easily do this using the jQuery library (http://jquery.com/)

Here is an example using `scrolling` as the div's ID attribute (you would need to add the ID attribute to your current div)
`$('#scrolling').hide()`

You can find more about this method here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/